# Unable to get button instance from DataGrid specific Cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Below is the .xaml code. i can get value of Status column and in next step i have to show/hide btnCancel button.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="grdUnConfirmJobs"  HeadersVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" MouseDoubleClick="grdUnConfirmJobs_MouseDoubleClick" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="White" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Ref}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Visible" Width="60"  />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Time}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Visible"  Width="35" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PickUp}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Visible" Width="250"  />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Destination}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Visible"  Width="180" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Status}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Visible"  Width="40" />    
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action" Width="auto" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="btnConfirm" Content="Confirm" Click="ConfirmButton_Click"  Height="auto" Width="auto"  Opacity="100" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <Button x:Name="btnDecline" Content="Decline" Click="btnDecline_Click" Height="auto" Width="auto"  Opacity="100" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" Click="btnCancel_Click" Height="auto" Width="auto"  Opacity="100" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I can read the Status column's values as below but could not get the btnCancel object to show/hide. Please anybody suggest what should I do.

```
    using (CabeeLocalDataContext db = new CabeeLocalDataContext())
    {

    var unCnfJobs = db.sp_ProcessingJobs(CurrentDateTime).ToList();
    grdUnConfirmJobs.ItemsSource = unCnfJobs;
    }

    grdUnConfirmJobs.UpdateLayout();

    foreach (sp_ProcessingJobsResult item in grdUnConfirmJobs.ItemsSource)
    {
    if (item.Status == "Cancellation Requested")
    {

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can't access controls by name when they are defined in DataTemplates. In order to change that button Visibility you have to use binding. I've made a simple example for this:

```
<Window x:Class="VisibilityStack.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:VisibilityStack"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Testing Visibility" 
                Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here is your codebehind with the DependencyProperty IsChecked which will be used for bindings. When the CheckBox will be checked, you will see the button, otherwise it's Visibility will be Hidden according to the below converter:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsChecked.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

And the converter:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool val = (bool)value;

        return val ?
          Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So, in your codebehind, if according to your business logic you need the button to be Hidden, or Visible just change that IsChecked property to true or false and the converter will do the job for you, transforming the booleans into items of the Visibility enumeration.